# created 4 textboxes in <tr> dynamically through javascript onclick of checkbox. i want to get the values textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the javascript code which creates 4 textbox in 4`<td>` in a single  on the click of checkbox. There are around 20 checkbox if all checkboxes are cliclked 20`<tr>` each with 4 checkboxes are formed. My question is how to get the values from these textboxes so that it can be inserted in the database.how to multiple insert these values one by one if multiple values are received.

```
    str+="<tr id='unchk"+$(this).val()+"'>";
    str+="<td  class='tp' >";
    str+="<input width='100%' type='type' value='"+$(this).val()+"'  readonly />";
    str+="</td>";
    str+="<td  class='tp'>";
    str+="<select>";
    str+="<option selected='selected' value='1'>Mr</option>";
    str+="<option value='2'>Miss</option>";
    str+="<option value='3'>Mrs</option>";
    str+="</select>";
    str+="</td>";
    str+="<td  class='tp'>";
    str+="<input width='100%' id='cname"+$(this).val()+"' type='type' value='' onblur='getval("+$(this).val()+");'/>";
    str+="</td>";
    str+="<td class='tp' >";
    str+="<input width='100%' type='type' value=''/>";
    str+="</td>";
    str+="<td class='tp' >";
    str+="<input width='100%' type='radio' name='primary' onchange='getval("+$(this).val()+");' value=''/>";
    str+="</td>";
    str+="</tr>";
    $('#pass').append(str);
```

here $('#pass') is the id of the div to which the entire rows are appende

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `name` to the text boxes being created and if you are using java, then you can get the values by:

```
request.getParameterValues("name_of_textboxes");
```

In Javascript, you can get the values by:

```
var textBoxValues = [];
$("input[name='name_of_textboxes']").each(function(){
  textBoxValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: there are 4 textboxes which can appear multiple times so if given same name the values can be taken? how to insert it into sql there would be such 4 arrays